# Swift 4 : Go to another screen if have parameter in Deep Link

Tags: ios, swift

**INTRODUCTION**
I'm still new use Swift, for now, I have a project using Swift, not develop form start just customize the App.

**PROBLEM**
Now I want to create Deep Link with Parameter. So, I try to follow a few tutorials from the internet e.g: [https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97] and [https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/custom-url-scheme-deep-link-ios-13-and-later-swift-5/] but not work.

**TRY TO DO**
I want to if App detects Deep Link have a parameter, App will go to another page and show the parameter.

Comment: what issu you are facing?

Comment: I don't know where must insert the code.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in scene delegate

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}

func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
    // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
    // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
    // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not necessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    
    if let url = URLContexts.first?.url{
      print(url)
      let urlStr = url.absoluteString //1
      // Parse the custom URL as per your uses, this will change as per requirement
      let component = urlStr.components(separatedBy: "=") // 2
      if component.count > 1, let productId = component.last { // 3
        self.pushToProductDetailSceen(productId: productId) // 4
      }
    }
}

func pushToProductDetailSceen(productId: String)
{
    
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
    // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
}

func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
    // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
}

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene[![enter image description here][1]][1]: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

[image]

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
    // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
    // to restore the scene back to its current state.
}
```

}

just put this line in safari and it will works.

testapp://productId=97

Comment: @cahanadboy, SceneDelegate is a file, right? if I don't have a file I must create a new file?

Comment: I am using xcode 11.7 and create new project then it will create sceneDelegate

Comment: If I don't have the file? how to do it?